# Geodjango multilingual site gives different results for location values

Tags: django

I have a multilingual django site. I am using geodjango to save locations. I am looping through locations to make a javascript array

```
{% for vE in venueEvents %}
    {% for v in vE.venues %}
        lArr.push([{{ v.location.y }}, {{ v.location.x }}]);
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In english site i get results as 41.0412229773  (  with a point )
But in turkish site i get 41,0412229773  ( with a comma )

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Format localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/formatting/) is a feature of Django.

You can turn it off for your whole project by setting `USE_L10N` to `False` in your settings, or just in that particular case, with `unlocalize` template filter:

```
{% load l10n %}
{% for vE in venueEvents %}
    {% for v in vE.venues %}
        lArr.push([{{ v.location.y|unlocalize }}, {{ v.location.x|unlocalize }}]);
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```